# What is this item and how do I use it?

Tags: resident-evil-6

I found this item in a drawer in the early stage of chapter 1 of Leon's story in RE6 but I don't seem to be able to interact with it in any way.

[image]

It looks like a classic Resident Evil puzzle piece which makes me think I might need it for something but it could just be an Easter egg.

Does anyone know what I am suppose to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shoot it.  Shooting Serpent Emblems unlocks collectibles (files and figures).